# Xamarin.Forms : Does anyone know what's the equivalent of WillEnterForeground and DidEnterBackground in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: mobile, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am rewriting an app that I wrote in Xamarin.iOS into Xamarin.Forms and I used to have some codes to execute on DidEnterBackground and WillEnterForeground. Now I can't find the equivalent method in Xamarin.Forms. I've tried mainPage.Appearing and mainPage.Disappearing in my App class but they seem to be different from what I am trying to achieve. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe that functionality is in Xamarin.Forms yet. You could install Xamarin.Forms.Labs (available on NuGet) and inherit your app delegate from XFormsApplicationDelegate. You can look at a [sample app delegate](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Sample.iOS/AppDelegate.cs) on the GitHub sources.

```
public partial class AppDelegate : XFormsApplicationDelegate
{
```

You would then need to register the IXFormsApp interface with a DI container:

```
    private void SetIoc()
    {
        var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer();

        var app = new XFormsAppiOS();
        app.Init(this);

        resolverContainer.Register<IXFormsApp>(app);

        Resolver.SetResolver(resolverContainer.GetResolver());
    }
```

Once the application has been registered on the DI container you would use it on your shared/PCL code through the Resolver. You would be subscribing to the Resumed and Suspended events.  [Sample here.](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Sample/App.cs)

```
        var app = Resolver.Resolve<IXFormsApp>();
        if (app == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        app.Closing += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Application Closing");
        app.Error += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Application Error");
        app.Initialize += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Application Initialized");
        app.Resumed += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Application Resumed");
        app.Rotation += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Application Rotated");
        app.Startup += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Application Startup");
        app.Suspended += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Application Suspended");
```

Comment: Thanks -- I was mistakenly attempting to resolve IXFormsApp with DependencyService which has approximately zero chance of working.